# How to solve $y' - \frac{y}{x} = x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $y' - \frac{y}{x} = x$

I've used the linear differential equation system in this picture:

[image]

$a(x) = -\frac{1}{x} , b(x) = x , A(x) = -lnx$ and I got to $y = 1 + c$

the answer is $y = Cx + x^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must go wrong in your work, the coefficients are right:
$$y = e^{\ln x} \left( \int xe^{-\ln x} \,\mbox{d}x + C\right)$$
Now note that $e^{\ln x} = x$ and $e^{-\ln x} = e^{\ln x^{-1}} = \tfrac{1}{x}$, so:
$$y = x \left( \int x\tfrac{1}{x} \,\mbox{d}x + C\right) = x \left( \int 1 \,\mbox{d}x + C\right) = x\left( x + C\right)$$

Comment: in the formula it is $e^{-A(x)}$ in the left one, which makes it $\frac{1}{x}$. Thus $y = e^{-ln x} \left( \int xe^{-ln x} \,\mbox{d}x + C\right)$ = $y = \frac{1}{x} \left( \int xe^{-\ln x} \,\mbox{d}x + C\right)$

Comment: But $A(x) = -\ln x$, so $-A(x) = -(-\ln x) = \ln x$.

Comment: You're right sir. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome and there's no need for *sir* :).

Answer (score 3):

The equation can be written as

$$\frac{xy'-y}{x^2}=(\frac{y}{x})'=1.$$

thus

$$\frac{y}{x}=x+C$$ and

$$y=x^2+Cx$$

where $\; C\;$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, for the general formula:

$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\text{a}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{b}\left(x\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $\text{r}\left(x\right)=\exp\left(\int\text{a}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\right)$.

Multiply both sides by $\text{r}\left(x\right)$:

---

$$\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{a}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{b}\left(x\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute:

$$\frac{\text{d}\text{r}\left(x\right)}{\text{d}x}=\text{r}'\left(x\right)=\text{a}\left(x\right)\cdot\exp\left(\int\text{a}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\right)=\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{a}\left(x\right)$$

---

$$\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}'\left(x\right)+\text{r}'\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{b}\left(x\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Apply the reverse product rule:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)=\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{b}\left(x\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$:

---

$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{b}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{K}+\int\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{b}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{y}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\text{r}\left(x\right)}\cdot\left\{\text{K}+\int\text{r}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{b}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\right\}$$

So:

$$\color{red}{\text{y}\left(x\right)=\exp\left(-\int\text{a}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\right)\cdot\left\{\text{K}+\int\exp\left(\int\text{a}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\right)\cdot\text{b}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\right\}}$$

Where $\text{K}$ is an arbitrary constant.